# Ajax front-end user registration form - not returning JSON

Tags: form, ajax, registration

I have a user registration form on the front-end of a site that is working well as a standard form, but when I try to use ajax submission, I'm getting an HTML response rather than JSON.

Here's the javascript I'm using

```
$('#register-form').submit(function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();

    var data = $(this).serialize();

    $.post('/', data, function(response) {

        console.log(response);

        if (response.success) {
            alert("success")
        } else {
            alert(response.error);
        }
    });
});
```

And this is my form code:

```
<form method="post" action="" id="register-form" accept-charset="UTF-8">
{{ getCsrfInput() }}
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="users/saveUser">

<h3>Create An Account</h3>
<p>By creating an account, you will be able to save your application progress. This is an optional step.</p>

<div class="row">
    <label for="email" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Email</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" {%- if account is defined %} value="{{ account.email }}"{% endif %}>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-6">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input id="password" class="form-control" type="password" name="password">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-6">
        <label for="password2">Confirm Password</label>
        <input id="password2" class="form-control" type="password" name="password2">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="actions">
    <p><input type="submit" id="form-submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-grey"/></p>
</div>

<span class="center">Already have an account? <a href="#" id="sign-in-form-btn">Sign In</a></span>
```

The response var is returning the entire html page rather than JSON data.

Is there a way to trigger a JSON response for the registration form?

Note, I'm able to use similar code for a front-end login form and it's working well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT**

**[Craft 2.4 is now available](http://buildwithcraft.com/updates/2.4), and the [users/saveUser](https://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/controllers/UsersController#actionSaveUser-detail) action will now return a JSON response for AJAX requests.**

*The original answer is still valid for <2.4 builds:*

No, there's no way to trigger a JSON response for the `users/saveUser` action.

Other [UsersController](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/controllers/UsersController) actions (such as `users/login` do return JSON for AJAX requests, so it might be an idea to [submit this as a feature request](http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com/forums/285221-feature-requests) – as a consistency measure, if nothing else.

For now, here's a couple of ideas for workarounds:

1. Write a plugin with a controller that wraps the `UsersController->actionSaveUser()` method somehow, or implements its own action (you could basically just [copy paste the whole `actionSaveUser()` from the core `UsersController`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pixelandtonic/Craft-Release/master/app/controllers/UsersController.php), changing it to return some JSON at the end).
2. You can set the `redirect` parameter (using a hidden input field in your form) to point to a template where you build the JSON yourself.

Form:

```
<form method="post" action="" id="register-form" accept-charset="UTF-8">
     <!-- Your form code -->
     <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="{{ url( 'path/to/your/template/or/a/route' }}">
</form>
```

Template for the redirect (notice the JSON header):

```
{% header "Content-Type: application/json" %}
{
    "success" : {{ account is defined and account.id ? true : false }}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I just added the feature request, and will give this a shot in the meantime. Cheers.

Comment: Nice – would be great if you'd give an update if/when you get it working; the above are just ideas and the JSON thing may or may not work as-is. It would be great to have a solid answer for other users having the same issue in the future.

Comment: I tried the redirect route, but I wasn't able to output meaningful error message because actionSaveUser() only calls the redirect on successful user creation. So I have some front-end validation in place now to test basic input errors. I did add a redirect to a JSON page, and since it only redirects on success, I'm just returning "success" from this page by default. Then if I don't see the success var (which I won't on error as it returns the whole index page) then I can assume there was an error. At this point the error is most likely due to a duplicate email address or invalid password.